# ODATA : Issue with "OR" Operator

Tags: odata

I am trying to create a ODATA Url with `OR` Operator.

I have two URLs which works fine and has a filter like shown below

```
CorporateAccountCollection?$filter=(Phone eq '%2B33 123456789' or Phone eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89')
```

and

```
 CorporateAccountCollection?$filter=(Mobile eq '%2B33 123456789' or Mobile eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89')
```

I tried to concatenate above 2 filter with another `OR` Operator , **which doesnt work**

```
/CorporateAccountCollection?$filter=((Phone eq '%2B33 123456789' or Phone eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89') or (Mobile eq '%2B33 123456789' or Mobile eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89'))
```

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thank you
Regards

Prat

Comment: "which doesnt work" are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @vc74 : I am testing in IE , it says Page cannot be found. If I use `and` between the 2 `or` , then i see some result. but i have to use `OR` only . 
 `(Phone eq '%2B33 123456789' or Phone eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89') and (Mobile eq '%2B33 123456789' or Mobile eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89')`

Comment: Page not found is simply the default response in many APIs when there are no results. 'Page not found' in APIs should be interpreted as 'Data not found'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your conditions are simply `OR`'d together, you do not use all those brackets to enforce execution. (The brackets shouldn't matter, but depending on the query parser that the API is using, double brackets can sometimes be mistakenly be interpreted as implicit `AND`

Your query should be:

```
CorporateAccountCollection?$filter=Phone eq '%2B33 123456789' or Phone eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89' or Mobile eq '%2B33 123456789' or Mobile eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89'
```

or if your like the outer brackets:

```
CorporateAccountCollection?$filter=(Phone eq '%2B33 123456789' or Phone eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89' or Mobile eq '%2B33 123456789' or Mobile eq '%2B33 1 23 45 67 89')
```

> there are no error messages in this scenario because the criteria is simply filtering out the rows that you are expecting to see.
>   There is no error parsing your query, which is where error messages would normally come from.

If that does not work, please provide the raw outputs from your two queries that do work so that we can help determine what else might be the problem.

> usually these issues come down to specific nounces with the strings and values you are comparing.